# Storing Images Externally

Tags: hosting, storage, bandwidth

I got a page, with not that much bandwidth, therefore I want to store the images externally on another server, that offers unlimited bandwidth. Any suggestions on how to do this, or maybe a better solution?

Answer (score 1):

[Image storage on different server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7300951/image-storage-on-different-server)

Check out this similar post, Facebook does it, Google does it, so it's a preferred solution to store images on another server. You can assign links to the images dynamically or statically from the external server and that's all you need to do! You need to take care of the hierarchy how the images are to be stored in the external server.

Comment: Thanks for quick reply, do you have any suggestions on a place where this would be rather cheap?

Comment: Flickr, Picasa, Photobucket, imageshack - there are plenty of free services out there. How big are your images? What is the total size in MB/GB

Comment: well, it's user submitted, max size is 5 mb

Comment: I think it is possible to get the plugins from imageshack and embed it in your website, so the users upload the photos directly on imageshack and you retain the links. This is possible if there are no licensing issues