# Want to show youtube like progress bar when page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube, progress-bar

I have seen web sites where when the page loads for the first time a youtube like progress bar is shown. When the progress bar completes, the page content is shown with a fade in effect. The web site address is `https://www.skysite.com/`

I have checked many links for a youtube like progress bar, but those pages are showing a progress bar like you, but they have no relation with the page content.

Here are some of the links to which I have consulted.

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18350370/youtube-like-progress-bar
http://onextrapixel.com/examples/youtube-like-ajax-loading-bar/index5.html
http://jsfiddle.net/ajaSB/3/
http://thuru.net/2014/10/05/youtube-like-progress-bar-using-nprogress-js-with-angular-js/
http://ricostacruz.com/nprogress/
```

Just guide me on how to show a youtube like progress bar, and when progress completes I would like to show page content.

Comment: The website you are refering to is using [pace](https://github.com/HubSpot/pace)

Comment: suppose my page content is big and take time to load. so i want to show youtube like progress bar when page content will be loading side-by-side.i want there must be sync between progress bar progress length and page content download. suppose progress length will be 15% when 15% of page content downloads completed. looking for idea how to achieve it and specially has no idea how to sync between page content download and progress bar progress length.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website you are refering to is using pace -
https://github.com/HubSpot/pace/

It listen to all ajax request and dom loading and display a progress bar while hidding the page. Once everything have been loaded, it displays the content.

You can preview an example of this library in action [here](https://h_stackoverflow_com.p.eager.works/questions/31812836/want-to-show-youtube-like-progress-bar-when-page-load/31813188#31813188) (yeah, inception power)

#### Update from comments:

Do you have 2 accounts ?
As I **already** said, this library *DOES IT ALL*. It tracks *EVERY* bytes being loaded after the script itself. It is **easily** customizable, and have a **clear** doc that you should ***read***. It allows you to watch for *dom elements* loading progression, *images/scripts/ajax* stuffs progression, or even your *long scripts*.

If you have only your main html page that is the heavy stuff you should consider changing your design and refactoring in small pieces.
And if you can't and still want to tracks the progress, you can put a simple script at the very top of your page that will:

- Send a HEAD http request for the same page with ajax. Just to know your total page size (Content-Length header).
- Display progress based on current page size (many way of tracking, most simple is something like `document.firstElementChild.innerHTML.length` (it won't be very precise))
- Once the page have been loaded, removes the progress bar

I gave you everything you need to make it work.

#### Edit2:

As I feel you will ask for more ... Here is a NodeJs example.
It simply create an http server, and serve a page with chunked content (and simulate lags ...). So the full page takes time to load.
The javascript display a text progression in real time.

```
var http = require('http');

function chunked(res, count) {
    res.write('<p>Chunked content n°' + count + '</p>');
    setTimeout(function() {
        if(count > 0)
            chunked(res, count - 1);
        else
            res.end('</body></html>');
    }, 1000);
}

function handleRequest(request, response){
    response.setHeader('Connection', 'Transfer-Encoding');
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset=utf-8');
    response.setHeader('Transfer-Encoding', 'chunked');


    response.write('<html><head><script>\n' +
        'var progress = 0; startLength = 825; TotalLength = 1090;\n' +
        'function track_progress() {\n' +
        '    console.log(document.firstElementChild.innerHTML.length);' +
        '    if(progress > 1000) {' +
        '        document.body.firstElementChild.innerHTML = "Progress: 100% - Done !";\n' +
        '        return;\n' +
        '    }\n' +
        '    \n' +
        '    if(document.body) {\n' +
        '        progress = (document.firstElementChild.innerHTML.length - startLength)* 1000 / (TotalLength - startLength);\n'+
        '        document.body.firstElementChild.innerHTML = "Progress: " + (Math.round(progress)/10) + "%";\n' +
        '    }\n' +
        '    setTimeout(track_progress, 500);\n' +
        '}\n' +
        'track_progress();\n' +
    '</script></head><body><p id="progress">Progress: 0%</p>');

    response.write('<p>Starting to send chunked content...</p>');
    chunked(response, 10);
}

var server = http.createServer(handleRequest);
server.listen(8080, function(){
    console.log("Server listening on: http://localhost:8080");
});
```

Comment: is it possible to show progress bar while page data download. suppose page data or content download 15% then progress bar progress will be also 15%. can we develop this kind of real time progress bar ? looking for guidance.

Comment: Javascript is interpreted by browser as soon as possible. So its able to track every loading. This plugins does all the tracking process and allow to customize the rendering in a very easy way.

Comment: suppose my page content is big and take time to load. so i want to show youtube like progress bar when page content will be loading side-by-side.i want there must be sync between progress bar progress length and page content download. suppose progress length will be 15% when 15% of page content downloads completed. looking for idea how to achieve it and specially has no idea how to sync between page content download and progress bar progress length.

Answer (score 0):

One option:

1. Redirect to a blank page with an empty progress bar.
2. Use javascript to fill the progress bar from 0% to 100%.
3. THEN use javascript to redirect to your content page.

Another option:

1. Hide all the content on your page (maybe use javascript to add 'hidden' to the divs -- there are a lot of ways to do that)
2. ...except for the progress bar.  Fill it from 0% to 100%.
3. Use javascript to hide the progress bar and show all of your content.

Comment: suppose my page content is big and take time to load. so i want to show youtube like progress bar when page content will be loading side-by-side.i want there must be sync between progress bar progress length and page content download. suppose progress length will be 15% when 15% of page content downloads completed. looking for idea how to achieve it and specially has no idea how to sync between page content download and progress bar progress length.

Answer (score 0):

When your page is loading, show a progress bar. 
Once content is loaded hide the progress bar.
You can use library like JQwidgets to create progress bar.

Comment: suppose my page content is big and take time to load. so i want to show youtube like progress bar when page content will be loading side-by-side.i want there must be sync between progress bar progress length and page content download. suppose progress length will be 15% when 15% of page content downloads completed. looking for idea how to achieve it and specially has no idea how to sync between page content download and progress bar progress length.