# How to load page in background before switching the view in ASP.NET MVC5

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

lately, when I was using GitHub I've noticed, that if you navigate through the pages before the new page is displayed, the page is firstly loaded in the background (async manners).

No view change is performed until the page is fully loaded. Loading progress is also visually presented to the users (that small blue bar on top of the page).

[image]

I was trying to find some info how to achieve something like this but with little to none success. Is anybody able to tell me, how to achieve similar behaviour?

Comment: You can make it with jquery. Example Question : https://stackoverflow.com/a/18350839/8175473