# Best protocol for CDN hosted jQuery library

Tags: jquery, html

I am using CDN hosted jQuery.

What is the effective difference between:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

and

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

*(with / without http prefix)*

Which method is "best" (safest, fastest)?

Comment: I think the 2nd option tells the browser to use whatever protocol is in use for the page as a whole, so if you switch your site to https your script-loads will be via SSL too.

Comment: Keeping the option of `https` open is always safer than forcing `http`...

Comment: The difference is that with the second example, the protocol (http vs https vs file) is selected for you automatically by the browser depending on how the entire page is being loaded.

Comment: One other warning - this was a long time ago, but I actually had a client where aspnetcdn.com was blocked by their firewall! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145277/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-cdncontent-delivery-network/5277337#5277337

Comment: I don't understand why this question has 3 downvotes. Seems legitimate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will use the HTTP protocol:

```
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

This code will use the HTTP or HTTPS protocol, depending on what protocol the page it's loaded on is using:

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
```

One important note is that when doing local development, the above will try to use the `file://` protocol, which will fail.

To get around this issue, you can use this code:

```
<script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
<script>!window.jQuery && document.write(unescape('%3Cscript src="ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-1.9.1.js"%3E%3C/script%3E'))</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Blake. What's the purpose of `document.write(unescape('%3Cscript` instead of just `document.write('<script`

Comment: That's a really good question. I sourced that portion from http://www.paulirish.com/2010/the-protocol-relative-url/ which references the HTML5 Boilerplate. But the HTML5 Boilerplate actually uses the syntax you noted: https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/src/index.html

Comment: By the way, Blake, I wish I could bump you another +1 for the note about local dev trying to use `file://` protocol -- a most useful tidbit. Hopefully others will help me out here.

Comment: You're too kind crashwap. Hopefully someone else can jump in here and enlighten us about your follow-up question.