# Which uses less resources (data and time) using font awesome.min.css locally or using it with the online link

Tags: html, performance, font-awesome

Which uses less resources while loading a website which uses font-awesome icons ?

using online link :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
```

or using locally downloaded fontawesome.min.css file and giving its link in html

Comment: CDN is faster. Because possibly already exists in cache.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the advantages and disadvantages of using a content delivery network (CDN)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2145277/what-are-the-advantages-and-disadvantages-of-using-a-content-delivery-network-c)

Answer (score 1):

The main benefit of having them on a CDN is that the files can be downloaded in parallel to files downloaded from your own website. This reduces latency on every page. So, the flip side of this is a pitfall of hosting locally - increased latency. The main reason for that is that browsers are limited in the number of connections that they can make at the same time to the same webserver. In IE6 this was defaulted to 2 concurrent connections to the same domain - shared between all open windows of IE!! In IE8 it is a bit better, defaulting to 6, which is inline with FF, but still, if you have a lot of images and you are not using sprites, you will experience heavy latency.

Using a CDN, I would always set the library version explicitly rather than getting the latest one. This reduces the risk of new versions breaking your code. Not very likely with jQuery, but possible.

The other main benefit of using a CDN is reduced traffic on your site. If you pay per GB or you are on a virtual server with limited resources, you might find that overall site performance increases and hosting costs come down when you farm off some of your content to a public CDN.

from - [Benefits vs. Pitfalls of hosting jQuery locally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832446/benefits-vs-pitfalls-of-hosting-jquery-locally)